# Delete custom metric and custom namespaces from cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Hi is there any way of getting custom metrics defined on cloudwatch log group be deleted along with its namespace. This is quite weird that we can create a custom metric/namespace using API/Console but cannot delete it either using API or Console from cloudwatch custom metrics/namespaces.[image: snapshot of custom namespaces/metrics in cloudwatch metrics menu.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's correct. You **can't delete** them. You have to wait till the associated metrics **expire**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html):

> Metrics **cannot be deleted**, but they automatically expire after **15 months** if no new data is published to them.

It could be worth nothing, that you are **not charged** for them. You are only charged when you put new data into them.

This is ongoing issue for years now, starting from 2011:

- [How could I remove custom metrics in CloudWatch?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=281904)

Comment: this is what happens if you keep on building new services and don't improve your existing services first